# How to remove the rind from Citrus Sugar?

Tags: fruit, sugar

I made citrus sugar a while ago (basically chopped up lemon rinds in a canning jar with sugar) and have now decided to remove the lemon before giving the sugar away.

So far I have tried wrapping the mixture in 2 layers of cheese cloth and scraping/sifting the sugar out from the bundle but this takes a long time and the cheese cloth develops holes that the rind also goes through.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the rind chunks are fairly large, you could use a colander with fairly large holes or a metal sieve.